# How to use cross validation in pytorch lightning?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am converting my tensorflow code into pytorch-lightning code. I was unable to find how to use cross validation in pytorch-lightning. Is their anyway to do it in lightningdatamodule.
I have kept my tensorflow code below where cross-validation is implemented using sklearn.

```
folds = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits = 5, n_repeats = 1)

for train_index, test_index in folds.split(left_input, targets):
    left_input_cv, left_input_test, targets_cv, targets_test = left_input[train_index], left_input[test_index], targets[train_index], targets[test_index]
    right_input_cv, right_input_test = right_input[train_index], right_input[test_index]
```

Comment: Your question doesn't point anything to ml modules either tf or pytorch. stratification is in the data preparing steps on model training stuff.

Comment: Yes, but in Pytorch Lightning preparing dataset comes into `LightningModule`. that is the reason i am asking

Comment: An example of using k-fold cross validation using PyTorch Lightning is provided [here](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/blob/874ae508707f135966cc1fa2c33428328547ab0a/pl_examples/loop_examples/kfold.py)

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like this, if using dataframe

```
for fold,(train_idx,val_idx) in enumerate(kfold.split(df)):
    print('------------fold no---------{}----------------------'.format(fold))
    train_split=df.loc[train_idx].reset_index(drop=True)
    val_split=df.loc[val_idx].reset_index(drop=True)

    model=OurModel(train_split,val_split,fold)

class OurModel(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self,train_split,val_split,fold):
        super(OurModel,self).__init__()
        
        self.train_split=train_split
        self.val_split=val_split
        self.fold=fold
```

if you are reading from image folder than you can do

```
combined=torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder('../multiclass/train/')

for fold,(train_idx,val_idx) in enumerate(kfold.split(combined)):
    print('------------fold no---------{}----------------------'.format(fold))
    train_subsampler = torch.utils.data.SubsetRandomSampler(train_idx)
    val_subsampler = torch.utils.data.SubsetRandomSampler(val_idx)
    model=OurModel(combined,train_subsampler,val_subsampler)

class OurModel(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self,combined,train_subsampler,test_subsampler,test_data=None):
        super(OurModel,self).__init__()

        self.train_subsampler=train_subsampler
        self.test_subsampler=test_subsampler
        self.combined=combined

    def train_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(DataReader(self.combined,aug),,sampler=self.train_subsampler,shuffle=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lambda transform or similar logic below. I am not sure, but this might help you. This is a 10-folds cross validation. Here cut is the size of image you want to crop (used for exclusion of background noice).

```
transform_test = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.TenCrop(cut_size),
    transforms.Lambda(lambda crops: torch.stack([transforms.ToTensor()(crop) for crop in crops]))
```

and pass this transform to your `test_loader`.